# How to display the username in an additional secured webflow in CAS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, cas

I'm working with a [cas](/questions/tagged/cas) implementation and want to extend it by adding a separate [spring-webflow](/questions/tagged/spring-webflow). The webflow will be used to manage user specific data that is hosted in a separate web-service. This webflow will be restricted such that a user must first be authenticated in order to access it.

I've added a new flow to `cas-servlet.xml` as follows:

```xml
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="builder">
    ...
    <webflow:flow-location id="profile" path="/WEB-INF/profile-webflow.xml" />
    ...
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

The first state in my `profile-webflow.xml` is a view to a page that should display the users username ...

```xml
<view-state id="accessView" view="profileAccessView" />
```

The `profileAccessView` refers to `profileAccessView.jsp` which I want to display the username of the CAS authenticated user.

```
<h2>USERNAME</h2>
```

**Is there a way to display the logged in users username here?**

I've tried accessing and binding the user info via [spring](/questions/tagged/spring), but I get a `null` result, i.e. ...

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CAS server, users are not authenticated by Spring Security. This question has been asked several times on the CAS mailing lists, I advice you to seek through them, like this one : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jasig-cas-dev/username/jasig-cas-dev/-vMzR51b5S0/wbjpdMItHLMJ.